# how to add a column with count values in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with names, attributes `a` and `b`, and then `cluster`.

```
+--------+-----------+----------+---------+
| names  | a         | b        | cluster |
+--------+-----------+----------+---------+
|  Johny | 225630096 |      447 |       3 |
|  Johny | 225630118 |      491 |       4 |
|  Johny | 225630206 |      667 |       5 |
|  Johny | 225630480 |     1215 |       6 |
|  Johny | 225630677 |     1609 |       7 |
|  Johny | 225631010 |     2275 |       8 |
|  Manny | 154247076 |     6235 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247079 |     6241 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247083 |     6249 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247084 |     6251 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247087 |     6257 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247090 |     6263 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247091 |     6265 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247093 |     6269 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247097 |     6277 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247098 |     6279 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247099 |     6281 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247100 |     6283 |       1 |
|  Manny | 154247555 |     7193 |       2 |
|  Manny | 154247629 |     7341 |       3 |
|  Manny | 154247630 |     7343 |       3 |
|  Manny | 154247633 |     7349 |       3 |
|  Manny | 154247634 |     7351 |       3 |
| Douges | 146340582 |     6811 |       1 |
```

I wanted to add a `count` column based on `names` and `cluster` column. For example, the output will contains count of clusters within each name. For example, output will look something like this:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+
| names  | a         | b        | cluster |count    |
+--------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+
|  Johny | 225630096 |      447 |       3 |    1    | 
|  Johny | 225630118 |      491 |       4 |    2    |
|  Johny | 225630206 |      667 |       5 |    3    |
|  Johny | 225630480 |     1215 |       6 |    4    |
|  Johny | 225630677 |     1609 |       7 |    5    |
|  Johny | 225631010 |     2275 |       8 |    6    |
|  Manny | 154247076 |     6235 |       1 |    1    |
|  Manny | 154247079 |     6241 |       1 |    1    |
|  Manny | 154247083 |     6249 |       1 |    1    |
|  Manny | 154247084 |     6251 |       1 |    1    |
|  Manny | 154247087 |     6257 |       1 |    1    |
|  Manny | 154247090 |     6263 |       1 |    1    |
|  Manny | 154247091 |     6265 |       1 |    1    |
|  Manny | 154247093 |     6269 |       1 |    1    |
```

I have tried to use `COUNT` function but, it seem to count the number of cluster instead.

Comment: Did you RTFM for [count()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)? What you want cannot be done directly with mysql, but can be faked with local variables within the select. `select if(@prev_name <> names, @count:=1, @count:=@count + 1) AS count ...`

Comment: It might make more sense to use python to do this, you think?

Comment: it'd certainly make the query easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery or variables.  The variables are typically more efficient:

```
select t.*,
       @rn := if(@name = name and @cluster = cluster, @rn, if(@name = name, @rn + 1, 1)) as `count`,
       @name := name, @cluster := cluster
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @name := '', @cluster := -1) const
order by name, cluster;
```

If you want to put this into a table (rather than results from a query) use `create table as` or `insert into`.

The subquery approach is:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct cluster)
        from table t2
        where t2.name = t.name and
              t2.cluster <= t.cluster
       ) as `count`
from table t;
```

The performance should be ok with an index on `table(name, cluster)`.  Note that this version could be used in a view.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. But the variable approach gave me a syntax error. I have tried to make sure the tabulator is same as written, but still keep getting an error at 
    `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table t cross join        (select @rn := 0, @name := '', @cluster := -1' at line 1`

and in the subquery approach, whats table t2?

thank you

Comment: @mshakya . . . "table" is supposed to be your table name.  That's how SQL works.